# VSCode: Refer to CMakePresets.json-defined (configure/build) environment variable in tasks.json and/or launch.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-tasks, cmake-presets

As the title says, with Visual Studio Code and CMake extension, in a C++ project that is configured via `CMakePresets.json` (define configure, build, test environments and compilers/toolchains), how can one refer to a environment variable defined in the JSON file?

For example, consider envvar `VM_IP` let's call it, that is different for each configuration: one VM for Ubuntu, another VM with Windows 10, and this is specified via "environment" property in `CMakePresets.json` for each configuration.

I would like to launch the target on the specific VM and use the appropriate IP *without* having to type IP in again duplicated in `tasks.json` (nor via its "envFile" property, as this is non-importable in `CMakePresets.json`)

Is there a macro expansion to call, perhaps something like `${cmake.configureEnvironment:VM_IP}`, in `tasks.json` to get the envvar value?

Comment: You checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#variable-substitution-in--launchvsjson-and--tasksvsjson)?

Comment: @ixSci Thanks for that, even though it's not what I'm looking for. The question is about Visual Studio CODE -- tried and doesn't work